# Kafka template connection with broker

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I've got a @KafkaListener method in my service which processes message and send it to another topic using KafkaTemplate and from time to time it completely stops working due to some reasons.

```
2022-10-04 16:53:18.218 ERROR 1 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='{"type":"INFORMATION","messageId":"f39fabfd-e560-499b-9850-440ad811657b","phoneNumber":"+100000000...' to topic ss.fb.processing-notifications.send:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic ss.fb.processing-notifications.send not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

2022-10-04 16:53:33.013  INFO 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Disconnecting from node -2 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 29794 ms.
2022-10-04 16:53:33.014  WARN 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker prd-mqueue-srv2.obi.ru:9092 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected
2022-10-04 16:53:41.005  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-nepcNotificationsGroup-1, groupId=nepcNotificationsGroup] Disconnecting from node -3 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 27831 ms.
2022-10-04 16:53:41.005  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-nepcNotificationsGroup-1, groupId=nepcNotificationsGroup] Bootstrap broker prd-mqueue-srv3.obi.ru:9092 (id: -3 rack: null) disconnected
```

There seems to be some network issues however after restarting the service everything works fine again. Anyway I wonder why eventually broker turns out to be disconnected? Is't producer supposed to infinitely try sending message to broker until it succedes?

Comment: retry limit is set for kafka producer, it cannot infinitely retry sending message by default.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_retries
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_delivery.timeout.ms

Comment: is there a workaround to make it reconnect after disconnecting from broker?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `KafkaTemplate` call in a `RetryTemplate` or `@Retryable` method - see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry - the `RetryTemplate` is already on the class path as a transitive dependency of spring-kafka.

Comment: hi gary, not sure that using internal kafka retry mechanism for each msg vs external retry mechanism which is better here. Trying to understand difference here.

Comment: The internal retries are for transient problems when the broker is up (retries up to `delivery.timeout.ms`); external is for when the broker is down (can't get metadata in `max.block.ms`.